# Is there a way to enable Chrome (or Firefox) to read web pages via another server on local network?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, ssh

My local machine is not connected to internet. However, I have a server on local network which I can connect via SSH. This server is directly connected to internet. I do not have the admin privileges on the server, so I cannot install a browser on it. However, I can download web pages on it using wget. I was wondering if there exists a way so that I can browse internet using a regular browser installed on my local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have SSH access to the server you can try using it as a proxy.

```
ssh -D 8765 user@host
```

Then you need to set a SOCKS5 proxy on your browser pointing to `127.0.0.1:8765` and you'll be ready to browse the Internet as long as the SSH connection is alive.

The port 8765 is used just for example. You can use any port between 1025 and 65535.

Comment: Thanks. I am able to open some websites on my browser, but my browser cannot open most of the websites. Also, I am continuously getting the following error on the shell:  
"channel X: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused"  
Where x, is a channel number.

Comment: Are you sure you can open that sites from the the server? This might help you http://superuser.com/questions/237977/ssh-dynamic-port-forwarding-connection-refused

Comment: Yes, definitely. Not a firewall problem. I can download any page using wget on the server.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked! Is there a command similar to ssh on windows? Can it be done using cygwin?

Comment: You can use PuTTY. It has the SOCKS5 option

Answer (score 0):

If it's allowing you to get webpages with wget, you might want to see if the server is set up to be a proxy server.

Comment: This would probably be better as a comment.

Comment: No, the server is not set up to be a proxy server.